# Selective with/in/about

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, syntactic-analysis, construction

I need to find out which preposition is more suitable for the sentence below;

> "Could we not just be selective ***with/in/about*** our potential themes."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are fine:

- Could we not just be selective with our potential themes.
- Could we not just be selective in our potential themes.
- Could we not just be selective about our potential themes.

[Source: Cambridge English Dictionary.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/selective)

The first feels the most natural to me.

Conversely, "selective on" is *not* valid English.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, can we say that the prepositions "with, in, and about" can be used interchangeably after the word selective in all instances?

Comment: I can't think of any examples where they're not interchangeable. (There is also "selective between", but oddly that usually means "capable of discerning", and is most common in scientific texts.)